# OWL: only one property among many properties exists

Tags: xsd, owl

I want to express the `xs:choice` element from XSD in OWL:

> XML Schema choice element allows only one of the elements contained in the  declaration to be present within the containing element.

I think maybe I should first define a property group in OWL, and then specify only one of the properties in the group is allowed exists. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think maybe I should first define a property group in OWL, and then
>   specify only one of the properties in the group is allowed exists. Any
>   help?

There's no notion of "property group" in OWL, but you could get a similar effect using subproperties and disjoint properties.  For instance, you could have a property hierarchy like this:

- hasVehicleChoice

  - hasCar
  - hasTruck

Then, you can declare that **hasCar** and **hasTruck** are disjoint.  That means that a individual can't have the *same value* for both properties.  That means that you can't say:

x hasCar vechicle72
        x hasTruck vechicle72

That's not enough to say that they can't have different values though.  You could still have

x hasCar vechicle72
        x hasTruck vechicle75

To avoid that, you could make **hasVehicleChoice** be a functional property (meaning each individual has 0 or 1 values for it, but no more), or use a subclass axiom with a restriction, like

Person subClassOf (hasVehicleChoice exactly 1)

Then, each person would have exactly one vehicle choice, and since **hasCar** and **hasTruck** are disjoint, the person can't have both.

All that said, this isn't a common pattern in OWL ontologies, and there's not a particularly convenient way of encoding it.  If you don't need it all that often, you might be better off just using the subclass axioms and property restrictions directly.  E.g.,

Person subClassOf ((hasCar exactly 1) and (hasTruck exactly 0)) or ((hasCar exactly 0) and (hasTruck exactly 1))